Data is not inserting in database When trying to use with store user data
I'm try to make forum app in asp.net core mvc using stored user data instead individual application user but the question by user is getting add in database but when i try to add answer of corresponding question posted  y another user or self it won't be add in database.

The SQL Query is

CREATE TABLE Forum_Questions (
    QId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Description TEXT NOT NULL,
    FK_UserId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_UserId) REFERENCES UserTable(UserID)
);

CREATE TABLE Forum_Answers (
    AId INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    Content NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    FK_UserId int,
    FOREIGN KEY (FK_UserId) REFERENCES UserTable(UserID),
    QuestionId INT,
    FOREIGN KEY (QuestionId) REFERENCES Forum_Questions(QId)
);



The Model OF Question

public int QId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> FK_UserId { get; set; }
   
public virtual ICollection<Forum_Answers> Forum_Answers { get; set; }
public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }


Answer Model

public int AId { get; set; }
public string Content { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> FK_UserId { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> QuestionId { get; set; }
    
public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }
public virtual Forum_Questions Forum_Questions { get; set; }


The detail function where details of question is shown and POST answer functionality.

public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var forum_Questions = db.Forum_Questions
        .Include(q => q.UserTable)
        .Include(q => q.Forum_Answers)
        .Include(q => q.Forum_Answers.Select(ans => ans.UserTable))
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.QId == id);

    if (forum_Questions == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    return View(forum_Questions);
} 


AddAnswer this the function actually where i got issues
also when i try to debugging it then it won't invoked

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddAnswer([Bind(Include ="Id,Content, QuestionId, FK_UserId")] Forum_Answers answer)
{
    int? userId = Session["UserID"] as int?;

    if (userId != null)
    {
        answer.FK_UserId = userId.Value;
        db.Forum_Answers.Add(answer);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    var question = db.Forum_Questions
        .Include(q => q.UserTable)
        .Include(a => a.Forum_Answers)
        .Include(a => a.Forum_Answers.Select(ans => ans.UserTable))
        .FirstOrDefault(q => q.QId == answer.QuestionId);

    return View("Details", question);
}


This View Of Details

<form asp-action="AddAnswer" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="Content" class="form-control" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto; height: 100px" placeholder="Enter Your Answer"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="IdentityUserId" class="form-control" value="@Model.UserTable.UserID" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="QuestionId" class="form-control" value="@Model.QId" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Answer" style="margin-right: 10px;" />
        <a asp-action="Index" class="btn btn-default">Back</a>
    </div>
</form>


I referenced This Code to make my application, the below code is used Individual Application User,

    public class QuestionsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public QuestionsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Questions
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var applicationDbContext = _context.Questions.Include(q => q.User).Include(c => c.Answers);
            return View(await applicationDbContext.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Questions/Details/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var questions = await _context.Questions
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .Include(q => q.Answers)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (questions == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(questions);
        }

        // GET: Questions/Create
        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Questions/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,Description,IdentityUserId")] Questions questions)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(questions);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(questions);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddAnswer([Bind("Id,Content, QuestionId, IdentityUserId")] Answers answer)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(answer);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            var question = await _context.Questions
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .Include(a => a.Answers)
                .ThenInclude(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(q => q.Id == answer.QuestionId);

            return View("Details", question);
        }

        // GET: Questions/Edit/5
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var userId = User.Identity.Name;

            var questions = await _context.Questions.FindAsync(id);
            if (questions.IdentityUserId != User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", questions.IdentityUserId);
            return View(questions);
        }

        // POST: Questions/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
        // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("Id,Title,Description,IdentityUserId")] Questions questions)
        {
            if (id != questions.Id)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(questions);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!QuestionsExists(questions.Id))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            ViewData["IdentityUserId"] = new SelectList(_context.Users, "Id", "Id", questions.IdentityUserId);
            return View(questions);
        }

        // GET: Questions/Delete/5
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var questions = await _context.Questions
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);
            if (questions.IdentityUserId != User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(questions);
        }

        // POST: Questions/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var questions = await _context.Questions.FindAsync(id);
            if (questions != null)
            {
                _context.Questions.Remove(questions);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> QuestionsList()
        {
            // Get the current user's IdentityUserId
            var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

            // Retrieve only the questions created by the current user
            var userQuestions = _context.Questions
                .Where(q => q.IdentityUserId == userId)
                .Include(q => q.User)
                .Include(q => q.Answers);

            return View(await userQuestions.ToListAsync());
        }

        private bool QuestionsExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Questions.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }


I tried show many things throw ChatGpt but any of the solution want worked.
I also tryed to use FK_UserId property but it won't worked.

Hi Timir, please open the developer tools and find the network tab. Please check the network trace after clicking the submit button. If face the 401 error, you can comment the [Authorize] attribute first for testing.

i tried as per your guide but it doesn't throw any error like 401.

Could you create a minimal sample for me? I will investigate it when I am free, please hide your sensitive information, many thanks

to store the data or... ?

Hi Timir, you can create a sample project for you, then I will use add-migration and update-database in my side.
